# bitbucket - dúvida sobre workflow, branchs e merge

Tags: git

Eu e a minha equipe começamos a trabalhar com o git para controle de versão (tarde eu sei), e usamos o bitbucket como repositório remoto (pois permite repositorio privado gratuito).

Bom, tenho algumas dúvidas para o workflow.

O programador esta trabalhando no branch master, pois é a base do projeto em andamento.

Eu estou trabalhando no branch "front-end", pois estou trabalhando nos estilos para o layout responsivo.

Como devemos proceder para sempre trabalhar com arquivos corretos?

Estou pensando, no fim do dia, dar um merge do branch "front-end" no "master", e depois dar um pull do master na minha base local e as alterações ir aplicando no branch "front-end" até finalizar o projeto.

Esta correto?

Answer (score 3):

Talvez esse fluxo te ajude.

Crie a branch:

```
git branch frontend
git checkout frontend
```

Mas se você quer que outra pessoa também possa contribuir com as alterações nessa branch. Você pode criar uma branch remota

```
git push origin frontend
```

para copiar uma branch remota localmente

Para que seus colegas contribuam numa determinada branch remota, precisam copiá-la localmente.

```
git checkout -t origin/frontend
```

Depois é só dar merge

```
git checkout master
git merge frontend
```

Para não ficar poluindo seu repositório, uma boa prática é remover branches que não são mais necessárias. Para isso, basta rodar o seguinte comando:

```
git push origin :frontend
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa é uma duvida de workflow com git, isso é comum de acontecer quando você deseja trabalhar com múltiplas branch's, eu vou mostrar o git successful workflow.

[Aqui](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) 
tem um bom exemplo de como trabalhar dessa forma, eu indico também ler sobre workflow com pull request, essa pode ser uma solução viável pra você dependendo da sua forma de entrega de software.

Comment: Ótimo link, muita gente trabalha assim

Answer (score 1):

Além das opções de *workflow* aqui apresentadas, pode ser interessante utilizar também de forma complementar algum sistema de Integração Contínua como o Jenkins, que pode ser configurado para automatizar os *merges*, *builds* e *deploys* da aplicação.